# Convert list (of string) from datareader to string

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list

I've captured some data from a datareader into a list and now I'm wondering what's the best way to put these out into strings.

The requirement I have is I need to grab field names from a table and then out put these as headings on a page.

```
 objConn = New SqlConnection(strConnection)
    objConn.Open()
    objCmd = New SqlCommand(strSQL, objConn)
    rsData = objCmd.ExecuteReader(0)

    If rsData.HasRows Then

        Do While (rsData.Read())

            Dim SubjectNames As New List(Of String)

            SubjectNames.Add(rsData.GetString("subject"))



        Loop

            SubjectList = SubjectNames.ToArray
```

Now I was thinking ToArray and was wondering how then to output all of the list entries into strings that I can then use later on.

It's also prudent to note that I'm doing this all inline as the CMS I have to use doesn't allow any code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you don't know how to convert a `List(Of String)` to a string. You can use `String.Join` and specify which string you want to use to join the words:

```
Dim SubjectNames As New List(Of String)
Do While (rsData.Read())
    SubjectNames.Add(rsData.GetString("subject"))
Loop

Dim headers As String = String.Join(", ",  SubjectNames)
```

Note that i've moved the declaration of the list outside of the loop because otherwise you would always create a new list for every record.

**Edit**: So you don't know how to access elements in a `List` or `Array`.

Elements in a `List(Of String)` or `String()` are already individual strings. You access each element via indexer. For example: `Dim firstSubject = SubjectNames(0)` or via `Linq`:  `firstSubject = SubjectNames.First()`. For the 10th element: `Dim subject10 = SubjectNames(9)` since indexes are zero based.

[MSDN: Arrays in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wak0wfyt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Is there a way to put all the results from the list into individual strings?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on those points - much appreciated.